# Set localStorage item to expire VS using cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

I am trying to have a banner be dismissable with a close button, I don't want it to reappear for 30 days once dismissed.

I have achieved the first part using localStorage like this...

```
if (localStorage.getItem('popup') != 'closed') {
  
    var x = document.getElementById("popup");
    x.style.display = "block";
  
}

function closePopup() {

    var x = document.getElementById("popup");
    x.style.display = "none";
    localStorage.setItem('popup','closed');
      
}
```

I am now trying to set the expiry and am starting to think I should have used cookies instead. Can I set expiry for localStorage items of are cookies the more suitiable thing to use in this instance?

Comment: You can't do this with `localStorage` you should use `cookies`.

Comment: I would prefer local storage over here. The cookies usually needs to be returned with every service request, while localstorage stays in the client machine and UI can directly take the decision there without sending it to the server.

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala You can't set an auto expiry date for `localStorage` items.

Comment: The way I implemented it was by setting the timestamp in localstorage and compared it with the new Date().

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala Yea, that requires a checking function in every page load event. So it is not preferred over `cookie`.

Comment: @anthony already answered it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217487/discussion-between-rinkesh-golwala-and-smakss).

Answer (score 1):

You could store the timestamp of when it is closed in `localStorage`, and then on initialization see if that timestamp is `>= 30 days` old and if so, show the popup and clear the timestamp from `localStorage`.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution, does using cookies offer any benefits over this method?

Comment: @fightstarr20 only if the server needs to know about the timestamp.